# Unable to pass parameter from Python to Javascript function using webkit

Tags: javascript, webkit, python-2.7

I have a very simple function in Python that passes a parameter to a function in Javascript

```
def show_hr(hr):
global web_view
web_view.execute_script("showHr(%d);" % hr)
```

The function in Javascript looks like this

```
function showHr(a) {
b = a;
}
```

This works when I run it on the Python shell, but when I run it from command line, it gives me the error `undefined @0: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: showHr`

I read about this error and it seems that when there's an error in the Javascript function, it gets overlooked and thus it cannot find the variable. But the same function runs perfectly well when I run the Python program from the shell, so where is this going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

just bumped into your question while looking for something else.

Could this be a scope issue with Webkit being launched a way or the other?
Have you tried something like

```
web_view.execute_script("window.showHr(%d);" % hr)
```

(if showHr() is defined right in the page, for instance)

Comment: Well, I don't see why that should be a problem, because the Javascript code is in a separate file.